# Delete non-alpha words from a list

Tags: python, list

Sorry for a probably nooby question, I'm pretty new to Python, and I tried to Google first a little.
I have a list of words and numbers and I want to create a list containing only words from it. When I iterate through a list like you see next I create a list of letters, not words.

```
words = ['1', 'example', '2.3', 'hello', 'etc']

cleared_list = []
for word in words:
    if word.isalpha():
        cleared_list += word

print(cleared_list)
```

Comment: try `cleared_list.append(word)`

Comment: Expected output would be:
['example', 'hello', 'etc']

Answer (score 1):

`+=` cannot be used like this here.

It doesn't crash with an exception because `word` is a *string*, and strings are *iterable*.

So `cleared_list += word` iterates through `word` to add each character to the list, so it doesn't work as expected.

You need

```
cleared_list.append(word)
```

to explicitly add `word` to the list.

That said, replacing the whole code by a list comprehension is probably more readable

```
cleared_list = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]
```